# Placing navigation arrows inside a div containing a table to scroll sideways

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a table that is dynamically populated by AJAX. There are several columns in the table. Thus the entire content of the table has been designed to scroll horizontally on overflow. But the user needs to use the keyboard arrow keys to move left and right. Instead I want to provide the user with two arrows placed on either side of the visible part of the table to go right and left much like a Bootstrap carousel. But here it differs slightly. When I scroll the page up/down, the arrows should also move up/down within the visible section of the table to allow the user to navigate.

I know how to scroll the table horizontally sideways on button click. But I cannot place these arrows at the either end of the visible section of the table. Can anyone suggest how can this be achieved by either CSS, Jquery or using both or any other approach.

The HTML code is given below -

```
 <div id="table_div" style="display:none;">
    <div style="overflow-x: scroll; position:relative;" id="tablecontent">
        <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead class="vd_bg-green vd_white">

                <tr>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Student Id</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Father's Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Start Year</th>
                    <th>End Year</th>
                    <th>Registration No</th>
                    <th>Roll No</th>
                    <th>Stream</th>
                    <th>Section</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table_body">
                <tr>

                <!--Dynamically generated data from AJAX goes here-->

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: i don't see the js code

Comment: Is the js JS code needed? It just adds the rows in the <tbody> section. I can take care of the scrolling with buttons.

Comment: @madalinivascu No need to be rude.

Comment: @Saber How about showing some CSS code?

Comment: First of all I am using a downloaded template for making the page. The class="table table-striped table-hover" is the one provided by the Bootstrap file. Can you be specific what CSS do you want to see?

Comment: @madalinivascu if putting two buttons in HTML page was all I needed, I could have simply looked up the net instead of asking it here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tuuga07h/

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks but I have already done this. I want the buttons to be showing hovering over the visible section of the table, not at the bottom like you did. Because there will be large number of rows generated from AJAX call, if they are placed at the bottom then the user will have to scroll down every time to click them. That is why I have asked it will be somewhat like a Bootstrap carousel (where the arrows are visible at the sides of the visible section of the list).

Comment: i retract my word, you need to learn css: https://jsfiddle.net/tuuga07h/1/

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks again but I have done that too. The id="table_div" lies within another div, which is nested within another. The page where the table lies looks like the facebook page when logged in. The table lies in the section where posts are displayed and the menu items placed to the left. So the problem is even if I use the fixed property the buttons are placed relative to the viewport. I want the buttons placed only in the id="table_div" wrapping the table. The effect will be the same as in your example. But all that with respect to the <div>id="table_div"</div>.

Answer (score 0):

try:
html:

```
<button class="left">left</button><button class="right">right</button>
```

css:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
button {
    position: fixed;
    top:100px;
}
.right {
    right:0;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true,
        "bPaginate": false
    } );

} );
$('button').on('click',function(){
     var pwidth = $('div.dataTables_wrapper').width();

    if($(this).hasClass('left')){
       $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft( $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft()-pwidth );
    } else {
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft($('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft()+pwidth );
    };


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tuuga07h/1/