# Add button to scroll table horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table with overflow set to auto inside it's container, and a locked first column. A horizontal scroll bar appears to see additional data, but I'd like to add a button too. The visitor would be able to use their mouse, the scrollbar, or the buttons, to navigate horizontally in the table.

How would I go about building this out?

I can get my code working with a div (https://codepen.io/gregbarbosa/pen/axjKbL), but not the table (https://codepen.io/gregbarbosa/pen/eojbrJ). My only guess is that the JS animate doesn't apply to tables?

```
$("#right-button").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#content").animate(
    {
      scrollLeft: "+=300px"
    },
    "slow"
  );
});

$("#left-button").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#content").animate(
    {
      scrollLeft: "-=300px"
    },
    "slow"
  );
});
```

[image: screenshot of table]

Comment: Hey Greg. StackOverflow isn't really a "general advice" or tutorial site. If you have written code that attempts to achieve your goal, you can share it and we can help you debug it. However, in its current form, this question is far too broad. For reference, check out [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @TylerRoper Sorry Tyler, adding samples now.

Comment: You might try looking at this answer that uses jquery datatable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938596/2683294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target `.table-responsive` instead of `#content`.

```
$("#right-button").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".table-responsive").animate(
    {
      scrollLeft: "+=300px"
    },
    "slow"
  );
});

$("#left-button").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".table-responsive").animate(
    {
      scrollLeft: "-=300px"
    },
    "slow"
  );
});
```

Here's an [updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vMabbo).

Comment: Thank you @bfl. This was the exact solution to my issue.